# How to check if my privacy has been compromised or to protect against such compromise

Tags: internet, security

I use my landlords wifi as part of rent. Is there a terminal command for seeing if he is monitoring me in any way, my passwords may be compromised as well...

I have changed my passwords, and would like to know of other steps to take to ensure that my system is secure against common approaches taken to spy on me.

What are the steps appropriate for this situation?

Comment: Possible off-topic question. You haven't related your question to Ubuntu at all.  This site supports Ubuntu, though if using wifi without encryption, yes it would be easy to spy (monitor & record) on the traffic, if you use https it'll be far more difficult etc.

Comment: Nope, there is no such command.

Comment: @Zanna Thank you for pinging me. I have posted an answer. Reid, if you find my answer useful, please consider accepting or upvoting it.

Comment: @v010dya FYI: OP can't upvote any post as of now due to lack of vote up privileges. Nevertheless, +1 to your answer.

Comment: You can use a VPN, but this is the wrong place for such a questio.  Here is the proper place.  https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18049/do-vpns-provide-sufficient-protection-over-public-wireless-networks

Answer (score 4):

It is actually easier to protect your privacy than to determine if your privacy has been compromised when you did nothing to protect it. Think of it as being akin to trying to determine if somebody has photographed you. Your body is reflecting photons all the time, and it is trivial to catch some of them and form a picture. Here is a similar problem, your computer sends (and receives) traffic, and if somebody can look at it, you will never know, unless you know what they use to look at you.

Protecting your privacy is the route that you should be taking. Depending on your need you can do the following:

Minor threat: Install a [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) plugin, which attempts to use HTTPS if it is available. Monitor that you do not send or receive information through means that do not involve encryption. You can also install something like GPG for your emails, this will make it significantly harder to attack you. For communication via an instant messanger you can set up an [Off the Record plugin for pidgin](https://otr.cypherpunks.ca/), it will allow you to check that you are talking to a person that you think you are talking to, and also to make it harder to intercept your communication.

Average threat: Set up and use VPN, make sure that it is a good VPN service and do not browse without using it. You will run into problems with some sites (stupidly) blocking everybody who is using VPN. But that is life.

High threat: Install something like [TOR browser](https://www.torproject.org/download/), use that instead of your regular proxy browsing. You will find that your connection is slow, and even more sites will be unavailable or work only partially.

Very high threat: For anything that is even partially sensitive use only real anonymous/psedonymous networks. Forget about connecting to a regular WWW for the most part. Set up and run a [Freenet node](https://freenetproject.org/). It will be slow, but within that network you can be somewhat sure that if you do not accidentally just say your name, you are somewhat safe.

Risk of death: Either disconnect from the Internet all together, or use Freenet, turn off Opennet, allow only connections to people that you know in real life and trust not to spy on you. This will mean that you will need to actually exchange node references, do that via encrypted channel or by physically handing them a USB stick with a reference.

In addition to all of this, you should also keep in mind that physical security of your machine is very important. Consider using encryption, if you are a single user of your machine you need at the very least whole disk encryption provided by LUKS+cryptsetup. If you have several other people who have login privileges on your machine, you will need a separate encryption of your home directory. Both of these approaches can be enabled when you are installing the system.